# Tensorflow extract_glimpse offset

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use the [*extract_glimpse*](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#extract_glimpse) function of tensorflow but I encounter some difficulties with the *offset* parameter.

Let's assume that I have a batch of one single channel 5x5 matrix called M and that I want to extract a 3x3 matrix of it.

When I call *extract_glimpse([M], [3,3], [[1,1]], centered=False, normalized=False)*, it returns the result I am expecting: the 3x3 matrix centered at the position (1,1) in M.

But when I call *extract_glimpse([M], [3,3], [[2,1]], centered=False, normalized=False)*, it doesn't return the 3x3 matrix centered at the position (2,1) in M but it returns the same as in the first call.

What is the point that I don't get?

Comment: Not an answer as such, but it seems to be a known bug in Tensorflow:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2134

Answer (score 0):

The pixel coordinates actually have a range of 2 times the size (not documented - so it is a bug indeed). This is at least true in the case of `centered=True` and `normalized=False`. With those settings, the offsets range from minus the size to plus the size of the tensor. I therefore wrote a wrapper that is more intuitive to numpy users, using pixel coordinates starting at (0,0). This wrapper and more details about the problem are available on [the tensorflow GitHub page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2134#issuecomment-262525617).

For your particular case, I would try something like:

```
offsets1 = [-5 + 3,
            -5 + 3]
extract_glimpse([M], [3,3], [offsets1], centered=True, normalized=False)
offsets2 = [-5 + 3 + 2,
            -5 + 3]
extract_glimpse([M], [3,3], [offsets2], centered=True, normalized=False)
```